# What happened with Titanium Desktop? Which packages are needed to start?

Tags: titanium, tidesdk

I've choosed Appcelerator Titanium Desktop for developing my first cross-platform application, based on some research on the web. The problem is that [Appcelerator stopped supporting it](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/01/the-future-of-titanium-desktop.html) but released it as open source to the community and now you're on your own. There seems that there are many continuing with the project. I'm not sure if I need to download Titanium Studio, Titanium Developer or Titanium Desktop SDK. What's each package for and which one do I need? Documentation on the website is not clear enough.

Comment: I improved the question and added link to the Appcelerator blog post that says they stop working on Desktop. Please don't downvote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I figured out:

- Titanium Developer is the app that manages your project, compiles/packages it. You code on your own text editor / IDE.
- Titanium Studio is the full Eclipse-based IDE. It also manages/packages your project like Titanium Developer but you code in there with coding hints.
- Titanium Desktop SDK (discontinued) is the SDK required to write desktop apps.
- Titanium Mobile SDK (or Titanium SDK after Titanium Desktop SDK discontinued) is the SDK required to write mobile apps.

I downloaded Titanium Studio and when I tried to create a new desktop project I figured out it said the Desktop SDK was missing. It was hard to find the Desktop SDK since Appcelerator released it to the community and stopped its development. [[blog post]](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/01/the-future-of-titanium-desktop.html) I could find [links for the 1.1 version](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/129786/could-not-locate-a-titanium-desktop-sdk-at-the-given-path). There is the [Appcelerator GitHub repository](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_desktop) for the 1.2 RC6 if you want to compile yourself. I didn't wanted to compile so I installed with the links following [this instructions](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Downloading+Titanium+SDKs+in+Titanium+Studio#DownloadingTitaniumSDKsinTitaniumStudio-ManuallydownloadingTitaniumSDKsfromaURL).

There are some guys that seem to be continuing the Desktop SDK project as [TideSDK](http://tidesdk.org/). They have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TideSDK/titanium_desktop) for the new development (though for now it seems to be just a clone of the Appcelerator repository with 1.2 RC6 without further development).

Answer (score 15):

Titanium Desktop has been taken over and renamed to [TideSDK](http://tidesdk.org).

Comment: You are a TideSDK Contributor ! :P Am I right ?

Comment: Yes I am TideSDK Contributor.

Comment: Great.. ! It's Nice..

Answer (score 0):

As they have said that they will remove titanium Desktop support from Studio also I will suggest you to use Titanium Developer like me. I am using Titanium Developer tool for mobile and desktop both development.

Comment: Where do I get Titanium Developer? Couldn't find the link? Also, what's the difference between Titanium Developer and Titanium Studio?

Comment: Titianium Developer is just tool used to manage project (create, delete, compile, eidt). It's not like a studio like you can edit files, open files etc. That you have to do in some text editor. I think they have taken down DMG of titanium developer tool after launching titanium studio. You can search on net if you can get it some where else.